# Is there a way to change the style of nested div on hover and focus?

Tags: html, css

I know the answer of how to change a style of nested `div` on one event but is there some way to change a style of a `div` to be the same style on `:hover` and on `:focus`? I have 4 different elements in some parent `div` that I want to change their styles like that each one will act the same when `:hover` and `:focus` on the parent `div`.

here is an example :

`HTML`:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">...</div>
    <div class="child2">...</div>
    <div class="child3">...</div>
    <div class="child4">...</div>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
.parent:hover , parent:focus {
    //some style properties for the parent div
}

.child1{
   //some style for child 1
}

.child2{
   //some style for child 2
}

.child3{
   //some style for child 3
}

.child4{
   //some style for child 4
}

/*
  Now the following is what I know but it 
  is long especially when I have to change divs' styles:
*/

.parent:hover .child1{
    //child1 on hover of parent 
}
.parent:focus .child1{
    //the same style as when hover 
}

.parent:hover .child2{
    //child2 on hover of parent 
}
.parent:focus .child2{
    //the same style as when hover 
}

.parent:hover .child3{
    //child3 on hover of parent 
}
.parent:focus .child3{
    //the same style as when hover 
}

.parent:hover .child4{
    //child4 on hover of parent 
}
.parent:focus .child4{
    //the same style as when hover 
}
```

Is there a shorter way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```css
.parent:hover .child1,
.parent:focus .child1 {
    /* child1 on hover/focus of parent */
}
.parent:hover .child2,
.parent:focus .child2 {
    /* child2 on hover/focus of parent */
}
.parent:hover .child3,
.parent:focus .child3 {
    /* child3 on hover/focus of parent */
}
.parent:hover .child4,
.parent:focus .child4 {
    /* child4 on hover/focus of parent */
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying but I want each div to act different from other child divs and I'm not allowed to use ID's , only classes